# Masonry JS responsive did not work

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

I created a layout using masonry js. All is good. But the problem is whenever I try to resize my browser my masonry layout does not go responsive. Here's what I did:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4 grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4 grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4 grid-item--height4"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 80
});
```

CSS:

```
/** grid system **/
.grid {
  background: #000;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 960px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 240px;
  height: 161px;
  float: left;
  /* vertical gutter */
  background: #000000;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.grid-item--width4 { width: 480px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 322px; }
```

Comment: Your grid has a fixed width so that makes sense?

Comment: hmm.. So should I make a media query for this? In this example http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj it is already fixed but when you try to resize the browser the tile is moving to the space when they are fitted.

Comment: Remove `width` and use `max-width` only (which you already have set).

Comment: Ok it's working now but the layout now the layout is messy. Thanks for the help.